# Implementing Socket.IO backend on Android in Java

Tags: websocket, socket.io, nanohttpd

I have a use case to run http backend on Android device (e.g. an http endpoint on the android device itself). Then I want to allow socket.io based clients be able to connect to it and exchange messages.

Socket.IO library does not provide any library to do that. Can i just implement nanohttpd-websocket and a client using socket.io?

Comment: Are the socket.io clients that will connect to your server going to be on the same device?  Or elsewhere on the internet?

Comment: A socket.io client cannot talk to a webSocket server.    You must have a socket.io client talk to a socket.io server.  socket.io is an extension on top of webSocket and both ends must match (both are plain webSocket or both are socket.io).

Comment: that does make sense. I ended up using okhttp3 websocket client.